# What is the better way to say, "I will wait until you ask me to start off"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am completely missing a simple word which means "an indication from someone that you can go ahead". Something like giving a green signal.

Comment: Often "green light" is used metaphorically as well. "I am waiting for the green light from Security". "It was green-lighted yesterday". "OK, so we got signoff? that's great. Give Deployment the Go-ahead".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Go-ahead](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/go-ahead) may suggest your idea of 'green light': (from TFD)

> - Permission to proceed:
>
>   - waiting for the go-ahead from the control tower.

Answer (score 10):

"I'll wait for your [approval](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/approval)."

> NOUN
>
> 1 The action of officially agreeing to something or accepting something as satisfactory:
>   *the road plans have been given **approval**
>
>   they have delayed the launch to await project **approvals***
>
> MORE EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *Detailed schemes for each area are still being drawn up and the first wave of project **approvals** are expected by the end of the year.
>
>   They are also awaiting payments and **approvals** under various schemes.
>
>   He added that all the relevant **approvals** for the project are in order right down to the environmental impact assessment.*

(Definition and examples from oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: I might be wrong here, but "approval" is less "you have permission" and more "I think this is good enough". To me, as a non-native speaker, approval doesn't sound enough as "permission".

Comment: @NateKerkhofs - Did you miss the example sentences cited by oxforddictionaries.com? They clearly show 'approval' being used in the sense of 'permission' or 'go-ahead'. (When you're in doubt about a particular usage, there's no better guide as to whether it is valid than observing whether, how, and to what extent native speakers apply it.)

Comment: I guess while "approval" might mean "an indication from someone that they have no objections with you going ahead", it need not mean "an indication from someone that you can go ahead". (necessary versus sufficient). "I'll wait for your approval" doesn't mean that I won't wait for something else even after you've approved.

Comment: @Pradyumna - Again: I refer you to the usage citations in my answer, which clearly contradict your interpretation.

Comment: @ErikKowal Thanks, yes, I thought about it again and I agree. "you can go ahead" does not mean "nobody will object if you go ahead" - it just means "I won't object if you go ahead". "Detailed schemes for each area are still being drawn up and the first wave of project approvals are expected by the end of the year." implies roughly the same thing as "Detailed schemes for each area are still being drawn up and the first set of authorities are expected to say 'you can go ahead' by the end of the year.

Answer (score 8):

You're very close, and Josh gets even closer.

> I'll wait until you give [me] the green light.

[CID](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+green+light):

> **give somebody/something the green light**
>
> to give permission for someone to do something or for something to
>   happen (often + to do sth)
>
> They've just been given the green light to build two new supermarkets
>   in the region. (often + to ) / The local prefect has given the green
>   light to the dam at Serre de la Fare.

And from the CDAI (same link):

> **give somebody/something the green light** also **give the green light to somebody/something**
>
> to give permission for something to happen
>
> She's waiting for her doctor to give her the green light to play in
>   Saturday's game.

Usage notes: also used in the form give a green light:

> The House of Representatives gave a green light to oil exploration off
>   the East Coast.

Answer (score 6):

The word you are looking for is **clearance**.

See here: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clearance

> NOUN
>
> Official authorization for something to proceed or take place:
>
> *the aircraft hadn’t got diplomatic **clearance** to land in Mexico*
>
> *he took off without air traffic **clearance***

Comment: It's a valid word, but I think it has to be said that it's less common in general parlance than some of the other answers.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Yes, it probably is less used, but the other words have additional baggage - e.g. `approval` implies that the approver has positive feelings regarding whatever it is; clearance doesn't have an emotional connotation.

Comment: Roger that ;) ...

Answer (score 4):

Less formally you would say "I'll wait for you to give me the nod."

Answer (score 3):

**[Cue](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cue)**: (from TFD)

> - A signal, such as a word or action, used to prompt another event in a performance, such as an actor's speech or entrance, a change in lighting, or a sound effect.

- The actor entered the stage on the director's cue.

Answer (score 2):

Pending [your] approval

I will take action X **pending your approval**

Comment: "I'll proceed with the task post your approval" could be the formal and courteous statement you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good options here, additionally one might say "I'm ready when you are." especially in a less formal setting.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the better way to say, “I will wait until you ask me to start off”?**

I do feel that it would be better if rewritten as"I will start as and when you instruct"

Answer (score 0):

you could say " I will wait".You could add to it when you have different situations, such as a patient is waiting to go visit the doctor, but the doctor is not present at the time. He/she says, "I will wait until the doctor shows up." 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your doctor example is not the right one as the OP asks for a better way to say “I will wait until you ask me to start off”. Also, your answer has already been posted by another user and doesn't provide any additional information. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.

Answer (score -1):

**Proceed** could be the right word.

Here are a few meaning and usage as per **thefreedictionary.com** :

1. To move on in an orderly manner.
2. To come from a source; originate or issue.
3. Law To **institute and conduct legal action**.

Comment: This is the *verb*, what you might do, when you receive the *noun* the OP is asking for.